# Component can't catch error from function passed as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I have a Form component, and when the submit button is clicked, it calls:

```
//Form.js
    //...
    const submit = () => {
            try {
                onSubmit(values); //onSubmit from props, values from state
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                setSubmitError(error);
            }
    }
    //...
```

I'm trying to use it with `onSubmit` passed as:

```
export const signIn = ({ email, password }) => (
    auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(e => { throw e })
);
```

But it doesn't handle it. In the current version, it throws an error to the console: `auth.esm.js:429 Uncaught The email address is badly formatted.` I tried wrapping the error with `new Error`, but then it throws it to the window. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal try/catch block cannot catch async errors. However you can declare an async block and this should work:

```
const submit = async () => {
            try {
                await onSubmit(values); //onSubmit from props, values from state
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                setSubmitError(error);
            }
    }
```